# ASP.net core 3.1: Javascript: window.open: Razor page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, window

I'm trying to open a razor page method in my javascript and I'm not sure why it opens on http, not https even though the url is set to https.

Below is my code:

Javascript:

```
function openWindowWithPost(url, data) {
  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.target = "_blank";
  form.method = "POST";
  form.action = url;

  form.style.display = "none";

  for (var key in data) {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "hidden";
    input.name = key;
    input.value = data[key];
    form.appendChild(input);
  }
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  var token = $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
  input.name = "__RequestVerificationToken";
  input.type = "hidden";
  input.value = token;
  form.appendChild(input);

  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
  document.body.removeChild(form);
}

function ButtonClickedEvent(){
    var inputJSON = '{"id": 1}';
    var url = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/Report/?handler=BatchReport';
    console.log('url: ' + url);    
    openWindowWithPost(url, JSON.stringify(inputJSON));        

}
```

Razor Page: Code behind:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> OnPostBatchReport([FromBody] InputParameter parametersJSON)
{
    var somestring = await getstring(parametersJSON);
    return somestring ;

}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{       

    services.AddRazorPages().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
    services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");


    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;                
        options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;                
        options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility();
    });

    // Sign-in users with the Microsoft identity platform
    services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration);

    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

    
}
```

My website is hosted at https://localhost:12345 and when I click on the button, I call the ButtonClickedEvent javascript function to open the report page in a separate tab. This tab has the protocol as http, not https.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hows your `launchsettings.json` looks like? Did you configured that accordingly?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, thank you. applicationURl was set to http. There was another issue in my JavaScript function that I fixed(RequestVerification name was missing). Could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the application `hostURL` it usually depends on `launchsettings.json` file configuration.

> To resolve this issue you should set `applicationUrl` under
> `launchsettings.json` as what you want it to while your application
> run.

***`launchsettings.json:`***

[image]

Hope it would guided you accordingly.